# Python script to search a JSON list for a value, then print a related key value

Tags: python, json, case-insensitive

New to Python and actually programming as a whole.

I'm trying to create a python script that will search through a JSON list, which has multiple sets of the same data.

eg.

```
  "data": [
    {
      "state": "WA",
      "country": "USA",
      "city": "Spokane",
      "population": 5124141"
    },
    {
      "state": "ON",
      "country": "CANADA",
      "city": "Toronto",
      "population": 3141412"
    },
    {
      "state": "CA",
      "country": "USA",
      "city": "Los Angeles",
      "population": 5124141"
    }
```

the list goes on for quite a while.

What I'm trying to do is create a script that will have two inputs, City & State.  Then once the City/State is typed in using input(), it will go through the entire JSON list and print out the population of the city/state entered.  Here's what I have so far but can't get it working.

```
cityinput = input("Please enter the city: ")
stateinput = input("Please enter your state or province: ")

res = requests.get('https://URL?search=' + cityinput + '/' + stateinput)
data = res.json()['data']

for city_details in data:
    if cityinput == city_details['city'] and stateinput == city_details['state']:
        print(city_details['population'])
```

Anyone have any pointers on how to get my for loop to search the whole json list for the city/state, then once found print out the population? Since the the variables will be input by the user, I would also like it to be case insensitive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like you have a good approach here. What do you mean by "can't get it working"? What happens when you run your program? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Hi Code-Apprentice. Thanks for your reply!  
actually, I was able to get it to work with the above, it displays the  population.

but what I didn't know is that it had to be case sensitive.  Is there anyway to ignore case sensitive on the input?

Comment: The only problem that I can point out in the approach is that you do not exit the loop once the city is found (considering that the cities are unique). To do that, you just need to add a "break" after the print.

Comment: As for the case sensitivity, you can apply the lower or upper methods to the strings to ignore it. For example, the condition  if cityinput.lower() == city_details['city'].lower() and stateinput.lower() == city_details['state'].lower(): will be case insentive

Comment: Thanks @henrique39 I'll give this a shot!

Comment: One way to compare strings ignoring case is to convert them all to either lower case or uppercase before doing the comparison.